# Uncaught TypeError: this.transitionTo is not a function in route

Tags: javascript, redirect, ember.js

I am trying to redirect my page to the homepage after I successfully delete the item but it is telling me transitonTo is not a function.

This is my code:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import Ember from 'ember';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

/**
 * @module lebtivity/routes/event
 */
export default Route.extend({
  /**
   * @type {Service}
   */
  api: service(),

  ajax: Ember.inject.service(),

  /**
   * @param {Object} params The parameters extracted from the URL.
   * @return {Promise<Object>}
   */
  model(params) {
    return this.get('api').request(`/events/${params.slug}`);
  },

  actions:{
    remove: function (model) {
        console.log(model.id);
        Ember.$.ajax({
               method: "DELETE",
               url: model.id,
               success: function(data)
               {
                 this.transitionTo('index');
               }
             })
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Try to change the `remove: function (model) {` to `remove: (model) => {`

Comment: as Yannick said but with the success function too.

Comment: It gives me a syntax error

Comment: have you got the answer? none of the answers work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be that `this` is not what you think. The scope of the variable `this` might be inside the promise success.

What you could do to check would be to define another variable before calling your DELETE

```
let that = this;
```

and use

```
that.transitionTo('index')
```

Comment: Instead of this, you could use arrow functions `success: () => { this.transitionTo('index')}`. Then there's no need to store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow functions. Write your actions and 'success' function like this:

```
actions: {
    remove() {
        $.ajax({
           ...
           success: () => { 
               this.transitionTo('index')
           }
        });
    }
}
```